# Get Excel cell relative reference into a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find how to get an excel formula to get a cell's relative reference into a cell.

A formula that would be like =getcellreference(B2) and then has B2 as the output.

Nothing complicated but i could not find a simple solution.

Comment: What I'm finding confusing is the "relative reference" part. A relative reference would be in relation to another cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CELL()`:

```
=CELL("address",B2)
```

For **formatting** to literally show `B2` instead of the absolute reference, you can do:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",B2),"$","")
```

Comment: @JRob23123 yay! If it works, you can flag it as The Answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the post.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is output a cell reference that you manually input, then all you need to do is:

`="B2"`

or

`B2` (no equals sign)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ADDRESS function to obtain the address of a cell in a worksheet, given specified row and column numbers

```
ADDRESS(row_num, column_num, [abs_num], [a1], [sheet_text])
```

So for cell B2, you will need to put `=ADDRESS(2,2)` where the first 2 stands for the row number and 2nd is for column B.